# How do I pick a domain name for a C programming website?

Tags: seo, domains

I want to make a blog but I am confused by its current [domain name](http://www.mycsnippets.blogspot.com/). I searched Google for the keywords and found these to be very rich:

- **C programming**
- **C language**
- **C language tutorials**

The problem is that I don't know how to choose a good domain name. I want my domain name to contain the maximum rich keywords for SEO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

General rule for girls and domain names: the ones you like are taken. You can still get one from a strange country, though.

I'm not sure how helful would my answer be to you but I don't think that if you are doing a programming related website, you must choose a SEF domain name. Take Stack Overflow, for example. People go there for the content. Programming geeks tend to go to communities recommended by their colleagues.

Besides, there are lots of C-related websites. In my opinion, your SEO strategy should start with long-tail optimization for uncommon problems which are more likely to drag people to your community.

Otherwise domain names are indeed a hard part and I really hope someone here is good with thinking of good ones.

Update 14 May 2015: try http://wordoid.com/ and http://naminum.com/ for name generation. Also, the new domain extensions are pretty neat.

Comment: +1, `General rule for girls and domain names: the ones you like are taken`

Comment: >> General rule for girls and domain names: the ones you like are taken.: u wot m9?

Answer (score 1):

The best bet with domain names is determine rather you are creating a one hit website (only targeting one term) or a long-term brand. If your goal is long term branding, your best bet is to go with a term relevant to programming in general. If your goal is that one term, you may be best off throwing together an exact match or otherwise, a very close one, as you mention.

But as Vergil detailed, most exact match domains have been taken - actually, all have - unless you're in a newly emerging - and mostly anonymous - market.

In this instance, I would first attempt to find qualifying .net or .org domains. These have shown to have secondary acceptance rates as compared to .com's, and still will draw a reputable amount of clickthroughs. The further down the TLD chain you get, to .us, .tv and etc, the less likely you are to get user respect, which pervades through all aspects of a site.

I can't spend the time to find you an exact domain, but if you are going with a longterm C resource, I would suggest a C+adjective derivative, which will likely still be available. This will help brand you but still help a bit with SEO.

CDialects
CommunicatingC

Are two ideas I just came up with off the top of my head. Good luck.